# Change scope to provided generates compile errors

Tags: maven, jboss7.x

I had a dependency declared as followed:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
        <version>${version.jboss.javaee6}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
```

When I change the scope to *provided* I get compilation errors such as *EJB cannot be resolved to a type*. I didn't understand, the documentation says that dependencies declared as provided are still used at compile time, and discarded only at deploy time.

So can someone help me understand these compile errors?

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
        <version>${version.jboss.javaee6}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Do you have multi-module maven project?

Comment: kindly check your effective pom by executing mvn help:effective-pom
check jboss-javaee-6.0 scope in that effective pom

Comment: yes I use a multi-module project

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is related to the `type` that you have mentioned in the dependency of that artifact.

Till now whatever I have played with Maven I cannot think of any case when one would need to add `pom type dependency`. Generally pom type packaging is used for parent module in a project (specify common project configuration like plugin versions, common dependencies, like log4j for example, repositories, properties etc.) and for utility package module (the one that assembles the project and does some other necessary things).

So, as a suggestion remove the type tag from the dependency until you need it for any specific purpose, let it be default i.e `jar`.

Comment: If I remove the pom type, I get the following error message: Missing artifact org.jboss.spec:jboss-javaee-6.0:jar:1.0.0.Final